# How to pass an array of stringvalues in Javascript with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code which works fine with one value i.e. excel. The code below highlight or mark the keyword "excel" in a textarea with the highlightWithinTextarea jquery plugin.

```
var skills = /excel/gi;

$('textarea').highlightWithinTextarea({
    highlight: skills
});
```

Now I'd like to pass multiple skills with regular expression. I have tried the code below but it doesn't highlight or mark the keywords in the textarea like in the example above with one word and regexp i.e. /excel/gi

```
var str =  ["excel","net","software","Microsoft"] ;

var skills = new RegExp(str, "gi");

for(var i=0; i<skills.length; i++)

$('textarea').highlightWithinTextarea({
    highlight: skills
});
```

So the question is, how do I pass an array with regexp in Javascript in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate between all elements in the array by putting a `|` between each:

```
const pattern = new RegExp(str.join('|'), 'gi');
$('textarea').highlightWithinTextarea({
    highlight: pattern
});
```

This will give you a pattern like

```
/excel|net|software|Microsoft/gi
```

(also, since your `str` is actually an array, not a string, you might find it less confusing to name it something like `arrOfWordsToHighlight`, or something similar - precise variable names improves code readability and helps reduce bugs)

Comment: Great, it works! thanks for your time and recommendations.